# Pass System Property to Application using Gradle and Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle

To run my application from the command line, I run:

```
java -Dconfig.file=./config/devApp.config -jar ./build/libs/myJar.jar
```

and inside my code, I have:

```
String configPath = System.getProperty("config.file");
```

Which gets the property just fine. However, when I try to debug using the built in debug Netbeans task, the property is null. The output of my run is:

```
Executing: gradle debug
Arguments: [-Dconfig.file=./config/devApp.config, -PmainClass=com.comp.entrypoints.Runner, -c, /home/me/Documents/projects/proj/settings.gradle]
JVM Arguments: [-Dconfig.file=./config/devApp.config]
```

Which is coming from:

[image]

I set it in both the arguments and JVM arguemtns to see if either would set it. Regardless of what I do, it is null. Can someone help me figure out how to set the system property so my app can get it?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the property on the Gradle JVM which has almost nothing to do with the JVM your application runs in. If you want to use Gradle to start your app for debugging, you have to tweak your Gradle build file to set or forward the system property to the `debug` task.

Assuming the `debug` task is of type `JavaExec` this would be something like

```
systemProperty 'config.file', System.properties.'config.file'
```

in the configuration of your `debug` task to forward what you set up in the "JVM Arguments" field in Netbeans.

Comment: As I don't know your debug task, no. You would have to share your gradle file for this.

Comment: I have no magic eightball, I cannot guess how his Gradle build file is looking. Without seeing his build file, I can hardly say how to modify it. I could only guess and that would help no-one.

Comment: @JeSuisAlrick why do you downvote me? My answer is as correct as it can be with the given information

Comment: @JeSuisAlrick just for you I added some guesswork now, happy? o_O

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "Arguments (each line is an argument):" and "JVM Arguments (each line is an argument):" fields provide values to the Gradle task itself. How I managed to pass properties over to the application was to append them to the `jvmLineArgs` argument (see image).

[image]

My application is now receiving the `profiles` property.

Thanks to @Vampire for the "guess work", lol!